# Custom Signals Scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, signals, scrapy

How would one go about implementing a custom signal in scrapy? My project implements a scoring system. Depending on the score of an item it is either accepted or rejected. I would like to be able to signal ITEM_ACCEPTED and ITEM_REJECTED to collect stats about the crawl.

I was looking at the source, https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/signals.py - but it was unclear to me what is going on here.

Any clarification on how to send this signal would also be helpful.

Any advice is appreciated!

Edit:
I found this on scrapy docs:

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#module-scrapy.signalmanager

One of my spiders:

```
from Scrapers.extensions import signals #my custom signals

def parse(self, response):
    manager = SignalManager(self)
    manager.send_catch_log(signals.ITEM_ACCEPTED)
    manager.send_catch_log(signals.ITEM_REJECTED)
```

my extension:

```
from Scrapers.extensions import signals as custom

@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    o = cls(crawler.stats)
    crawler.signals.connect(o.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
    crawler.signals.connect(o.spider_error, signal=signals.spider_error)
    crawler.signals.connect(o.item_scraped, signal=signals.item_scraped)
    crawler.signals.connect(o.item_accepted, signal=custom.ITEM_ACCEPTED)
    crawler.signals.connect(o.item_rejected, signal=custom.ITEM_REJECTED)
    return o

def item_accepted(self):
    print "it worked -- accepted"

def item_rejected(self):
    print "it worked -- rejected"
```

signals

```
ITEM_ACCEPTED = object()
ITEM_REJECTED = object()
```

Comment: @rockheartsm4l were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were instancing a new signal manager instead of using Crawler's one so replacing this line:

```
manager = SignalManager(self)
```

You can use this to get the actual signal manager:

```
manager = self.crawler.signals
```

It worked [for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870872/custom-signal-not-being-handled-by-scrapy-internal-api/30871705#30871705)

Comment: Where were you a year ago when I needed this?!?! Thanks for the answer though :D

Comment: :P i answered for the sake of knowledge, Are you still working with Scrapy?

Comment: Last summer I had an internship where I was using scrapy and I actually just started a full time position at the same company yesterday! So this information might become relevant to me again soon!

Answer (score 0):

Well, scrapy comes with an API that gives you access to all kinds of stats: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/stats.html

> class scrapy.statscol.StatsCollector
>
> get_stats()
>
> Get all stats from the currently running spider as a dict.

Edit:
To accept or reject items, just use a validation pipeline, and use DropItem: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html#dropitem

Comment: Yes I'm already using those features. My problem is that I don't want to base this off item_scraped or item_dropped. I'm keeping the item no matter if they were accepted or rejected. The only difference is where they are persisted to. So, the signals scrapy has in place don't cut it for me.