# Custom signal not being handled by Scrapy internal API

Tags: python, signals, scrapy

I am trying to handle a custom signal '**signalizers.item_extracted**' in a Scrapy extension 'MyExtension' which is successfully enabled when scrapy starts. Here is my code:

**signalizers.py**

```
# custom signals
item_extracted = object()
item_transformed = object()


class MyExtension(object):

def __init__(self):
    pass

@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    # first check if the extension should be enabled and raise
    # NotConfigured otherwise
    if not crawler.settings.getbool('MYEXTENSION_ENABLED'):
        raise NotConfigured

    # instantiate the extension object
    ext = cls()

    # connect the extension object to signals
    crawler.signals.connect(ext.item_extracted, signal=item_extracted)

    # return the extension object
    return ext

def item_extracted(self, item, spider):
    #Do some stuff
```

Then i try to send the '**signalizers.item_extracted**' signal but i think is not handled, or at least i can not either see the actual output nor debug it :

**In the spider:**

```
SignalManager(dispatcher.Any).send_catch_log(
   signal=signalizers.item_extracted, 
   item=item, 
   spider=spider)
```

Am i doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading a few Scrapy's source code i figured out the problem was on creating a new Signal manager instance instead of using crawler's one:

```
spider.crawler.signals.send_catch_log(signal=signalizers.item_extracted, item=item, spider=spider)
```

Now It is properly handled by the extension